# Docker + PHP 7.4 Could not open input file: /usr/local/lib/php/pearcmd.php

Tags: php, docker

Got the error when trying to update PHP in Docker (FROM php:7.2.18-fpm-stretch) up to 7.4.

> Could not open input file: /usr/local/lib/php/pearcmd.php
> The command '/bin/sh -c if ! [ -z ${http_proxy+x} ]; then pear config-set http_proxy $http_proxy; fi     && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y     && apt-get install -y librabbitmq-dev libssh-dev     && pecl config-set php_ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini     && pecl install amqp' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would recommend reading  [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  on how to write a quality question. This helps for better understanding for the contributers.

Answer (score 1):

And the solution is usage FROM php:7.4.15-fpm, not just FROM php:7.4-fpm